# What does "this.x" mean in java?

Tags: java, class, instance

Can someone please explain? As well as give a short and simple example. Thanks!

Comment: `this` refers to the current object instance. `x` must be an attribute of the class.

Comment: ah ok, I'm just not sure how to use it properly

Comment: I'd upvote this and the answer below, but I'm out of votes for the day :(

Comment: You need to read a good Java book or set of tutorials.  One off questions are not an efficient way to learn a language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is a reference to the current object, and is implicitly passed into non static methods. 
`this.x` dereferences the reference to get to the "x" attribute.

Use it if you want to disambiguate between a function argument and a class member.

```
public void setX(int x)
{
    this.x= x;
}
```

It is valid but redundant in this scenario:

```
public void setX(int xValue)
{
    this.x= xValue;
}
```

Or simply:

```
public void setX(int xValue)
{
    x= xValue;
}
```

Comment: So int x is equivalent to this.x?

Comment: Yup it is indeed. For that particular object of course. Remember that objects have their own memory location.

Comment: It's a reference, not a pointer.  Despite the similarities, they are distinct.

Comment: It's only equivalent if the `int x` appears at class level.  If it's at method level, x will be a local variable.

Comment: All right, thanks so much @Lews Therin

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen The Java Programming Language book doesn't distinguish between the two, but if you like I'll change it.

Comment: @perldog93 No problemo. But I'd listen to Matthew and get a good programming book. This is Java 101 ;)

Comment: @LewsTherin, the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1) is clear that the primary term is reference.  The key difference is that you can't do pointer arithmetic on references.

Comment: @LewisTherin Haha I have one for school, it's just that sometimes the book(Deitel) can be hard to understand, so I came to you guys :D.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen Agreed, that is the difference (among others). I just said pointer because it was lesser to type. I'll be more correct in the future :)

Comment: @perldog93 Understandable. And also remember that the attribute has to be a class member and not a local variable. 
Head First Java might be better to start with ;)

Comment: @LewsTherin Right. I'm beginning to get my head around it. Thanks again, I'll check out that textbook as well.

Comment: Just to nitpick, I disagree with the claim that `int x` and `this.x` are equivalent. `int x` declares a variable while `this.x` accesses that variable (if it is declared as a member variable). So the two are related but not equivalent.

Comment: I should have expressed myself clearly. Syntactically, they aren't equivalent. But if `int x` is an instance variable, then `this.x` *refers* to field x for that object in memory.